# Aspnet core build pipeline in vscode, especially typescript - in 2020

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, build

I'm trying to add Typescript to my VS Code ASP.NET Core MVC application for its wwwroot client scripts.  The tutorials I've found talk about full Visual Studio's way of compiling-on-save, but VS Code doesn't do that.  I've been in the node stack for a while, and used ASP.NET back before VS Code and folder-based projects.

How is the build pipeline managed/augmented?  How can I add a typescript compilation step to it?  And btw, how are client-side's packages supposed to be managed?  nuget?

I guess I could treat the client scripts as a separate project's bundled output and use yet another script to build both the typescript and the asp.net project in series, but I don't want to have to do all that if the csproj's build can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular or react starting from one of the dot net projects would be the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Otherwise you will need to setup all the parts manually:

1. Install Node.js Package Manager
2. Install typescript with node package:

   npm install -g typescript
3. Follow steps to setup compile and debug in:

   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

   and

   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging

Also see:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial